# Why am i getting undefined of my variable?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im fetching data in my ReactJs app from the Google Custom Search API. Im storing the data in an object called resultData using useState Hook.

Search.js:

```
const Search = () => {    
  
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [resultData, setResultData] = useState({});
  
  function searchInGoogle(e){

    const BASE_URL = `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1`
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_KEY;
    const SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY;    
    var apiCall = `${BASE_URL}?key=${API_KEY}&cx=${SEARCH_ENGINE_KEY}&q=${searchText}`

    axios.get(apiCall).then(function (response){
      console.log(response.data)
      setResultData(response.data)
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
    
  }

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value)
  }
  
   const items = resultData.items.map((item)=>{
    return <div key={item.id}>
      <h3>{item.title}</h3>
      <p>{item.htmlSnippet}</p>
      <hr />
      </div>
  }) 

  return (
    <div>
      <input className='searchInput' onChange={handleInputChange} ></input>
      <button className='btn' onClick={searchInGoogle} >Submit</button>
      {/* <Searchbar /> */}
      <div>
        {
        (Object.keys(resultData).length || Object.keys(resultData.items)) !== 0 ? <>
        <p>
          About {resultData.searchInformation.totalResults} ({resultData.searchInformation.formattedSearchTime} seconds)
          </p>
        <h3>{items}</h3>
        <p>description</p>
        </> : <><p>No results</p></>
        }

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

The issue i have is at line 31 that is the following block of code:

```
const items = resultData.items.map((item)=>{
return <div key={item.id}>
  <h3>{item.title}</h3>
  <p>{item.htmlSnippet}</p>
  <hr />
  </div>
```

})

And the error im having in my console is the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: resultData.items is undefined
```

I have the idea that it might get undefined as i run my app because the object is empty, but how can i avoid/solve this? Or is there any reason my variable is getting undefined?

Comment: Did you try to put few console logs to see what your "resultData" actually is before the render?

Comment: Yes, an empty object @OktayYuzcan

Comment: When it is an empty object, how you expect to use .map on undefined (items) ? resultData.items is undefined

Answer (score 1):

The axios call is asynchronous, so by the time the code reaches that line `const items = resultData.items.map((item)=>{`, it will trigger an error as `resultData` is still an empty object. You can use a combination of optional chaining operator(`?.`)/nullish coalescing operator (`??`) to achieve what you want.

```
const items = resultData.items?.map((item)=>{
return <div key={item.id}>
  <h3>{item.title}</h3>
  <p>{item.htmlSnippet}</p>
  <hr />
  </div>
}) ?? [] // return an empty array in case the result is undefined
```

---

I just saw that you displayed a "no results" message in case the array is empty. In that case, you'd have to add a new state variable, `loading`, that you will set to true before the call to axios and set to false when the result is returned so that you can display a loading icon or something else while the data is being fetched.

Comment: Still getting undefined, but it makes sense what you are saying.

Comment: Of course, it won't magically turn `resultData.items` into something that is not undefined. This was merely so that don't you get an error while the data was being fetched.

Comment: @mateoghidini sorry, I misplaced the optional chaining operator. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks at list the error message changed now. I have to figure how to convert an undefined to an object. But it really helped.